# Error to import Network from keras.engine.topolgy

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I installed the topology package by downgrading the keras (pip install 'keras==2.1.6' --force-reinstall), because it doesn't exist in newer versions. I am still getting an error to import Network.

```
Trying:
from keras.engine.topology import Network

Error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'Network' from 'keras.engine.topology' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py)
```

If Network doesn't exist then how can I get this so that rest of the code (CycleGAN) can use Network(). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What code are you talking about, and why does it need Network?

Comment: I am getting this error in HybridDetectionGAN model for underwater image enhancement. This model further uses CycleGAN model. In this code they used the Network(). Below are the sample code lines. from [link](https://github.com/LongChenCV/HybridDetectionGAN) model.

self.D_A_static = Network(inputs=image_A, outputs=guess_A, name='D_A_static_model') 
self.D_B_static = Network(inputs=image_B, outputs=guess_B, name='D_B_static_model')

Comment: by the way your link is broken, at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the correct version of Keras installed.

if you downgraded to version 2.1.6 make sure the Network class is available in that version.

`pip install 'keras==2.1.6' --force-reinstall`

Or you can use Functional API

```
from keras.layers import input 
from keras.medels imort model

# Assuming image_A and guess_A are your input and output layers

 image_A = Input(shape=(...))
 guess_A = ...  # Your model architecture for guess_A

self.D_A_static = Model(inputs=image_A, outputs=guess_A, name='D_A_static_model')
```

Comment: What is the full import path to Network?

Comment: i'm not sure if i got  your question
 but the Network is depredated in the newest version in keras but they added alternatives.

Comment: If I wanted to import Network, how do I do it.  From tensorflow.keras.?…

Comment: Yes that's one way to do it.
But i think it's better if  you consider using the Keras Functional API or updating your code to be compatible with the newer versions.

Comment: I will use the Functional API later when I have more time.  Right now I need to work on code I’m not familiar with and get it working before vacation.  If someone gives me the precise import package for Network I will give them the bounty.

Comment: You need to downgrade to  a Keras version before 2.2.0; but make sure you have a tensorflow version that's compatible with it; 

in this case you'd be able to import it like :

`from keras.engine.topology import Network`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `Network` class from an older version of `Keras`, you can install that specific version and need to make sure you are compatible with an appropriate tensorflow version 1.x

Copy the following into a `requirements.txt`

```
tensorflow==1.15.4  
keras==2.1.6
# Add other dependencies as needed
```

Then do within your project directory:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

*PS: Without a link or a MVP this is hard to check. Would appreciate if you could try and report back.*